# nx.Graph adding edges from a tuple in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and need some help please.

I have a the edges for a network graph as a tuple in python:

```
edges = [(198704060004, 198704060010), (201501250041, 201501250045), (198608190006, 198608190007)]
```

and I am trying to plot a network graph. The code below only plots the first tuple pair.

```
import networkx as nx
g= nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(edges[0][0], edges[0][1])

nx.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

Can you please help me to make it automatically add all the edges. I tried writing a for loop but it seems I am writhing something wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over `edges` and then add them one by one:

```
for source, target in edges:
    g.add_edge(source, target)
```